# Rewriting C++ template for C

Tags: c, templates, compression

Can anyone help me in rewriting this code from C++ to C... (it has templates... yeeee :))
Thank you.

```
template <class T>
void SWAP( T& t1, T& t2 ) 
  { 
    T tmp=t1; 
  t1=t2;
    t2=tmp;
  }
```

and this one

```
template <class CMP, class Element>
void sh_qsort( Element* array, uint lo, uint hi )
  {
    some code...
  }
```

and the sh_qsort is called like `sh_qsort<TEST>( test_file, 0, 255 )`
where `TEST` is

```
struct TEST {

static int  c( uint* A, int x, int y ) 
{
  uint px = A[x];
  uint py = A[y];
  int r,s;
  s = (px<py) ? SWAP(px,py),0x80000000 : 0;
  byte* p = &f_buf[px]; 
  byte* th = &f_buf[blocksize];
  byte* q = &f_buf[py];
  for(; (r=1,p<th) && ((r=(*p)-(*q))==0); p++,q++ );
  return r^s;
}

static void s( uint* A, int x, int y )
  {
    SWAP( A[x], A[y] );
  }
};
```

and how to rewrite this struct in c.

Simple and neat... HELP :)

Thank you!

Comment: The simplest way to do this would be to use `#define swap(x,y)` and tell it what to do. I'm not big on macro magic, but if you can search for macro functions and/or post what you have tried so far, people will be more inclined to help you. This smells like homework.

Comment: Do you realize that there is no direct equivalent of these features in C? You cannot simply rewrite, you need to change the function’s interfaces substantially; and depending on what you require, the solutions will be quite different.

Comment: That code is horrible. You could start by making the code readable C++, by adding proper indention and spaces to the code, and by letting each statement be on a line of its own. Then make intuitive, meaningful variable names instead of one-letter obfuscations. And finally split up complex expressions several less complex ones. Once that is done, the code can be rewritten in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `sh_qsort()` actually is a quicksort implementation, all you need to do is refactor `TEST::c()` into a comparison function as expected by `qsort()` from `stdlib.h`.

Going from compile-time generic code via templates to runtime-generic code via `void *` normally carries a performance penalty, of which you could get rid of by using so-called 'X-macros' to simulate templates with the preprocessor. However, there's probably no need to bother: As `TEST::c()` is sufficiently complex, it probably won't be inlined anyway, and you only have to pay for the use of the runtime-generic swaps performed by `qsort()`.

Comment: Well, `sh_sort` sounds more like shell sort, don’t you think?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys, its the result of http://encode.ru/threads/1230-On-compressing-series-of-ones-and-zeroes.
and I written the program which he's trying to translate.
Anyway there's a more C-like implementation in http://ctxmodel.net/files/BWT.cpp